# Bootstrap-tour onNext does not work properly

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

Can somebody tell me please how this plugin works http://bootstraptour.com/api/ ? I have a step there where I want to redirect to dynamic url. So I write onNext callback which looks like code below. Redirect works fine, BUT on the next site I see the same step. Not next but the same stupid step. Can somebody tell me what is wrong with this code? It drives me crazy...

```
    { // 18
        orphan: true,
        title: "Zakázky",
        content: "Výborně, Vaše první zakázka je založena. Klikněte na její modrý název pro pokračování.",
        path: basePath + '/commission',
        onNext: function () {
            var commissionId = $('.tour-commission-detail').first().data('id');
            if( ! commissionId )
            {
                alert('Nejdříve musíte založit aspoň jednu zakázku');
                tour.prev();
                return;
            }
            document.location.href = basePath + '/commission/overview/' + commissionId;
            return (new jQuery.Deferred()).promise();
        }
    },
    { // 19
        orphan: true,
        title: "Zakázky",
        content: "Nyní se nacházíte na přehledu zakázky. Vidíte zde všechny základní informace. <br>V dalších krocích doplníme " +
            "na zakázku zaměstnance, materiál a další náklady."
    }
```

Comment: It looks the problem is in (jQuery.Deferred()).promise() call. But it is necessary because otherwise popup shows before redirect....

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is in this line**

```
return (new jQuery.Deferred()).promise();
```

However it's necessary for the modal not to open before the redirect.

**To solve the problem**

```
{ // 18
    orphan: true,
    title: "Zakázky",
    content: "Výborně, Vaše první zakázka je založena. Klikněte na její modrý název pro pokračování.",
    path: basePath + '/commission',
    onNext: function () {
        var commissionId = $('.tour-commission-detail').first().data('id');
        if( ! commissionId )
        {
            alert('Nejdříve musíte založit aspoň jednu zakázku');
            tour.prev();
            return;
        }
        document.location.href = basePath + '/commission/overview/' + commissionId;
        return (new jQuery.Deferred()).promise();
    },
    onHidden: function(tour) {
        tour.setCurrentStep(18);
    }
},
{ // 19
},
{ // 20
    orphan: true,
    title: "Zakázky",
    content: "Nyní se nacházíte na přehledu zakázky. Vidíte zde všechny základní informace. <br>V dalších krocích doplníme " +
        "na zakázku zaměstnance, materiál a další náklady."
}
```

**Explanation**

The *onHidden* function will mark step 18 as current, preventing it from repeating itself. However, this causes a step to be skipped (in this case, step 19).

Then we leave step 19 blank as in the example above, so when the back button is pressed will find step 19 blank and skip it by going to step 18.